# HTML third party form js initialisation

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, materialize

I'm using [materialize css](http://materializecss.com/) and i want to add the [date picker](http://materializecss.com/forms.html). I've added `<input type="date" class="datepicker">` in my html file, but when i want o add

```
$('.datepicker').pickadate({
    selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
    selectYears: 15 // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year
  });
```

to my controller, it doesn't work, the page simply loads a basic date picker, not the expected one. Here's my controller:

```
 ( function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module( 'app.campaign' )
        .controller( 'campaignCtrl', campaignCtrl );

    campaignCtrl.$inject = [ '$scope' ];

    /* @ngInject */
    function campaignCtrl( $scope ) {
        console.log( 'krydsac' );
        $scope.submit = function () {
            var name = $scope.name;
            var date = $scope.datepicker;
            var duration = $scope.duration;
        };

        $( '.datepicker' ).pickadate( {
            selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
            selectYears: 15 // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year
        } );
    }

} )();
```

My linter says this:

> Warning
>   W117 - '$' is not defined.at line 19 col 9

But I can't see the problem :( 
Hope you can help me!

Comment: seems you need to jquery library

Comment: @user2181397 what do you mean? can you be more explicit? it is my first angular app :)

Comment: Include `<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"   integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>` in your code before including angular script and check if it is working

Comment: ya he is right your project needs jquery to be added , Angular can work with or without jQuery. If loaded without jQuery already loaded, it'll use jQLite which only has a handful of jQuery functions.So if you plan to use jQuery in your App  makes sense to load it before Angular which will prevent jQLite from being loaded at all.

Comment: @user2181397 i've added the script but the problem stays the same

Comment: here's my index.html: https://codeshare.io/0a4gO

Comment: @Issue429 jquery is loaded 3 times in that codeshare. Ensure it's only loaded once, that might help

Comment: @ADyson even when i use them once, the problem stays the same